# tex4ht cannot handle image in subfolders?

Tags: tex4ht

```
tlmgr revision 35841 (2014-12-16 20:11:15 +0100)
tex4ht revision:    34624
```

I was using [this](https://github.com/peterwittek/test-latex-converters) package for test the tex4ht functions. However, I found out if the image is under subforder, oolatex cannot process the figures correctly (the image in ODT file will display as 'read error' in both libreoffice and openoffice 4.1.1). If we move the figures out, the image can be correctly embedded into odt file. Any reason why this is happening, is there any additional config I should do to fix this?

Comment: it seems that pictures in the `odt` file must be only in the `Pictures` folders, not any subfolders. `tex4ht` apparently copies subfolders here and it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `tex4ht` support for `ODT`. I submitted a [bug report](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?240).

All pictures should be placed in `Pictures` directory in the `odt` file, but subdirectories are created for files which were originally in subdirectory of the compiled document.

To fix that, we need to modify configuration of image handling and some commands in `tex4ht.env`. We need to change links to images from Pictures/subdir/imagename to Pictures/imagename. At the same time, we need to track path to the actual image file, so it can be copied to the correct location.

You linked some test package, I will use that as basis for tests. There is a config file, `myconfig.cfg`.

Basic configuration for handling image inclusion is `\Configure{graphics*}`:

```
\Configure{graphics*}
   {png}
{\Picture[IMG]{imagename.png}}
```

we need to provide such configuration for each graphics type. imagename is saved in `\Gin@base` macro by `graphicx` package, but it contains full path. `\Picture` command is responsible for printing image element and we need only base name here. To strip path out, we can use `etoolbox` list processing commands:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareListParser{\getImgFileParser}{/}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\getImgFile[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\def\imgBaseName{##1.#2}\def\imgBase{##1}}
  \def\ImgFullName{#1.#2}
  \getImgFileParser{#1}
}
```

we declared `\getImgFile` command, with two parameters, file name and suffix, we save full path in `\ImgFullName`, we will pass this to the copy command later. `\getImgFileParser` process each part of path delimited by `/` and save it with and without suffix to two macros. Since imagename is the last part, it will be saved after processing.

We can use this macro in a following way:

```
\Configure{graphics*}
   {png}
{\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{png}
   \Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.png}}
```

we need to use `\expandafter` to expand `\Gin@base` contents.

Now we need to configure image element, with `\Configure{IMG}`:

```
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{IMG}
  {\ht:special{t4ht>\ImgFullName.4og}%
\ht:special{t4ht*>}%
\ht:special{t4ht<\ImgFullName.4og}%
\OOmanifest{<manifest:file-entry
    manifest:full-path="Pictures/\imgBaseName"/>\Hnewline
}%
%
   \ht:special{t4ht=<draw:frame
      draw:name="\imgBaseName"
      text:anchor-type="as-char"  % "paragraph"
%      svg:width="...pt"
%      svg:height="...pt"
      draw:z-index="0"
    >%
      <draw:image\Hnewline
         xlink:href="Pictures/}}
  {\ht:special{t4ht=" \Hnewline
         xlink:type="simple"
        xlink:show="embed"
        xlink:actuate="onLoad"
\ifx\noBoundingBox\UnDefined
   \string svg:width="\the\Gin@req@width"
   svg:height="\the\Gin@req@height"
\fi
        /><!--draw:name="}}
  {" }
  {\ht:special{t4ht=" }}
  {\ht:special{t4ht=--></draw:frame>}}
\catcode`\:=12
```

this configuration is copied from `ooffice.4ht`, I only changed file paths utilising `\ImgFullName` and `\imgBaseName`. I also added code for image dimensions.

Full contents of `mychonfig.cfg` with configurations for all supported image formats:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareListParser{\getImgFileParser}{/}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\getImgFile[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\def\imgBaseName{##1.#2}\def\imgBase{##1}}
  \def\ImgFullName{#1.#2}
  \getImgFileParser{#1}
}
  \Configure{graphics*}  
      {pdf}  
      {\Needs{"convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
                            \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}%  
\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{png}
   \Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.png }}  
\Configure{graphics*}
   {gif}
   {\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{gif}
\Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.gif }}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {png}
{\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{png}
   \Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.png}}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {jpg}
   {\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{jpg}
\Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.jpg}}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {jpeg}
   {\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{jpeg}
\Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.jpeg }}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {svg}
   {\expandafter\getImgFile\expandafter{\Gin@base}{svg}
\Picture[IMG]{\imgBase.svg }}
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{IMG}
  {\ht:special{t4ht>\ImgFullName.4og}%
\ht:special{t4ht*>}%
\ht:special{t4ht<\ImgFullName.4og}%
\OOmanifest{<manifest:file-entry
    manifest:full-path="Pictures/\imgBaseName"/>\Hnewline
}%
%
   \ht:special{t4ht=<draw:frame
      draw:name="\imgBaseName"
      text:anchor-type="as-char"  % "paragraph"
%      svg:width="...pt"
%      svg:height="...pt"
      draw:z-index="0"
    >%
      <draw:image\Hnewline
         xlink:href="Pictures/}}
  {\ht:special{t4ht=" \Hnewline
         xlink:type="simple"
        xlink:show="embed"
        xlink:actuate="onLoad"
\ifx\noBoundingBox\UnDefined
   \string svg:width="\the\Gin@req@width"
   svg:height="\the\Gin@req@height"
\fi
        /><!--draw:name="}}
  {" }
  {\ht:special{t4ht=" }}
  {\ht:special{t4ht=--></draw:frame>}}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{figure} 
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}    
% This one removes the rulers. Taking a look at html4.4ht should make 
% clear what has been changed.
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\HCode{}}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\EndPreamble
```

Now we need to modify contents of `tex4ht.env`. Find location of the file with

```
kpsewhich tex4ht.env
```

and copy it to the current directory. On `unix` systems, change following lines:

```
.4og mkdir -p              sxw-%%0.dir/Pictures/%%1
.4og rmdir                 sxw-%%0.dir/Pictures/%%1
.4og cp    %%1             sxw-%%0.dir/Pictures/%%1
```

to

```
.4og cp    %%1             sxw-%%0.dir/Pictures/
```

on Windows, some other commands are used, but changes should be similar.

Now we are done with image inclusion, there is just small issue with your example. `tex4ht` can't find bounding box of the image and it is rendered too small. Use

```
ebb imagename
```

command to create bounding box info and in the TeX file change

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

to

```
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
```

after compilation with

```
mk4ht oolatex test_case_mk4ht myxhtml
```

the result is following:

[image]

Comment: The bug seems to still persist in the current MikTeX distribution.

I have my images in a subfolder "img" (which is declare using `\graphicspath{ {./img/} } `.
The images are included using e.g.   ´\includegraphics{testimg.png}`

Compiling my tex file with 
`htlatex %MANUALNAME% "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo" "--enable-pipes"`
leads to the following log output 
`System call: copy ./img/testimg.png sxw-testfile.dir\Pictures\./img/testimg.png`
 `Syntax error`
If I put the image in the directory of the tex file, the image is found and everything works as it should.

Comment: @Mik ahh, could you please try to locate tex4ht.env file (it should be in `texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/windows/tex4ht.env`, find the line starting  `.4og copy...` and change it to `.4og copy  %%1        sxw-%%0.dir\Pictures\%%~n1.%%~x1`. I am not sure whether it will work

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work like this. The system output is `System call: copy testimg.png  sxw-testfile.dir\Pictures\~n1.~x1` which is probably not quite what you wanted to achieve...

Comment: @Mik that's bad. I don't have access to Windows currently, so I can't fix it, I can take a look next week.